# Problems when Installing Rpackages arulesViz and H2o in DSX cloud

Tags: r, data-science-experience

I'm using RStudio in DSX cloud and trying to install the packages using Packages / Install.

The errors are below:

1. installation of package ‘arulesViz’ had non-zero exit status
2. installation of package ‘h2o’ had non-zero exit status

Any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right there is an issue installing "arulesViz". That's because that package is looking for a version of "arules" that won't work with R 3.3.2. What you'll also run into is that installing the latest version of "arules" also won't work since it requires R 3.4 and above.

So, here's what worked for me ... and hopefully for you, too.

1) Install "arules" 1.5-4 (one version away from the current 1.5-5). That's because this version will install on R 3.3.2. Apparently, DSX R is looking for a really old version of "arules" which doesn't like 3.3.2, which is why we have to manually do this:

```
require(devtools)
install_version("arules", version = "1.5-4")
```

2) Now, install "arulesViz":

```
install.packages("arulesViz")
```

3) Load the package, which will pick up your new "arules" library:

```
library(arulesViz)
```

Next, installing "h2o" was pretty straight forward:

```
install.packages("h2o")
```

I didn't have a problem installing that one. So, try again. Otherwise, if you could post the error you got then I can investigate further.

For more information on installing libraries on DSX see: https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/importing-libraries.html

**Update (April 2019)**

IBM Data Science Experience is now called IBM Watson Studio