# Installing arulesViz in R-studio

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to use `arulesViz` in **R-Studio**, if I run:

```
library(arulesViz)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in library(arulesViz) : there is no package called ‘arulesViz’

So trying to install it:

```
install.packages("arulesViz")
```

Getting the following ERRORs and warnings:

```
ERROR: dependency ‘mvtnorm’ is not available for package ‘fpc’
* removing ‘/home/robb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/fpc’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘fpc’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘fpc’ is not available for package ‘dendextend’
* removing ‘/home/robb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/dendextend’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dendextend’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘dendextend’ is not available for package ‘seriation’
* removing ‘/home/robb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/seriation’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘seriation’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘seriation’ is not available for package ‘arulesViz’
* removing ‘/home/robb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/arulesViz’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘arulesViz’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmptN9Ozx/downloaded_packages’
```

As adviced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482376/problems-when-installing-rpackages-arulesviz-and-h2o-in-dsx-cloud?rq=1) I tried to run this so:

```
require(devtools)
install_version("arules", version = "1.5-4")
```

But once again I'm missing `devtools`, so I try to install it and get the same warning. What's my problem? I previously istalled `arules` with no problem, I don't get what the problem could be here.

I also installed the following packages as suggested by R-studio itself:

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

But that doesn't solve the issue.

Here's my output of `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=it_IT.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=it_IT.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=it_IT.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=it_IT.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=it_IT.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=it_IT.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=it_IT.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.4 tools_3.4.4
```

Comment: Please add output of `sessionInfo()` to your post.

Comment: @zx8754 done! :)

Comment: I assume that its not an R issue but a dependency issue (as the installation brakes after a while and it had a non-zero exit status). Do you see any ERROR message in the console output?

Comment: @David thanks for your comment: I added the part of the output with the ERROR messages

Comment: Can you try to install the missing packages individually to pinpoint the error, i.e., `install.packages("mvtnorm")`. I guess you are still missing some non-CRAN dependencies (similar to `libssl-dev`)